# PHP / Text File Saving / FTP - Emailing Error (with some 3dsMax for fun)

Tags: php, email, ftp, phpmailer, 3dsmax

I'm currently facing a funky error that's consuming my day, any help or insight is appreciated.

The setup:

1. Generate a .txt file on a Linux server with PHP
2. Email the .txt file to an email account
3. Outlook saves the email in a folder
4. 3dsmax has a script running and reads the .txt file for action.

The problem:
All of a sudden 3dsmax is spitting out an error "Compile error: Bad Number or time syntax" and breaks. It used to work fine.

The weird part:
If I open the .txt file in WordPad, save it as a new .txt file, the script works fine. Alternatively, if I download the .txt file from the server to the local machine via ftp, the script works fine. Let's say I rename the .txt file to .zip on the server, download it and rename it back to .txt ... script breaks.

What could be causing this to happen? 3dsmax issue? the way the .txt file is saved? sent? Why would FTP of the file be different than email or direct download?

The txt file is generated like:

```
$fh          = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
$nl          = "\n";
$stringData  = 'blah blah 3d stuff'.$nl;
$stringData .= 'blah blah 3d stuff'.$nl;
fwrite($fh, $stringData);
fclose($fh);
```

and sent using PHPMailer class.

Comment: on fwrite i tried ($fh, utf8_encode($stringData)); with no luck either

Answer (score 0):

Forced binary and/or Windows break fixed the bug I believe.

fopen($myFile, 'w') to fopen($myFile, 'wb')
and $nl = "\n"; to $nl = "\r\n";